# Google Maps v3 zoom produces artifacts squares not loading

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

We are using the Google Maps v3 Web api and are getting weird graphical aritfacts after zooming the map. 
The problem does not always occur, but perhaps 30% of the time.

Has anyone experienced this problem before?

```
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&sensor=false"></script>
```

[image: Google maps graphical problem]

Comment: What OS/browser? Can you reproduce the issue with a simple map out of your project?

Comment: Have you tried not using `v3.exp`? Does it still happen calling a different version?

Comment: Hi, I just changed to v3.exp and the problem still persists.